# Indentation and floats

Tags: floats, indentation, typography

I usually only allow paragraphs to be indented when there's a *need* for them to be: only if the previous "element" could be confused and thus "merged" with the paragraph in question.

In practical terms, this means that there's no indentation after a `\medskip` or `\bigskip`, nor after `itemize` or `enumerate`, nor after displayed math.

Now, when typesetting floats it's hard to enforce this style: I'd like to leave no indentation after a float (in my opinion, it's hard to confuse things here).

Given, a paragraph may well finish "flush" to the right margin and continue a new sentence just after the float...

The "solution" I'm looking for then would be to *force* floats to occur (as many as need to) *inside* paragraphs, so that the first letter after the float is a lowercase, non indented, letter.

Any ideas?

PS: I usually also set `\setlength\parfillskip=2em plus 1 fil`, so as to have a consistent "visual clue" that a paragraph is over.

Comment: "*Forcing* floats to occur *inside* a paragraph" - does that mean you still want them to float? How about you make a mockup of what you're after for a specific float that you have in mind and post a graphic of it.

Comment: Let me clarify (I'm pretty bad at this, sorry). I'd like the floats to float normally, but they should _always_ break up a paragraph in two, so as to have the first part of said paragraph, the float, and then the final part of the paragraph. Hope that helps. I'm not in a LaTeX capable computer right now... as soon as I get to one I'll post an example (assuming I find one =P).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put simply: you can't.

LaTeX decides to output floats after it has decided to break a page, but when the output routine comes into action paragraphs have already been typeset, so avoiding the indent just after a float is out of the question. You might be able to put top floats above the final part of a paragraph, in some cases, by setting a high negative `\interlinepenalty` (say `\interlinepenalty=-500`) so as to encourage TeX to break pages between lines of a paragraph, but the cure can turn out to be worse than the disease. (In my dialect we say "*pezo el tacon del buzo*", the patch is worse than the tear.)

In my opinion, you start from a wrong assumption: the indent *is* always necessary, unless after a *big* interruption, that is, a heading. Some typographic traditions do indent paragraphs also after headings.